# Finding the earliest time we can schedule

Tags: python, array, numpy

We have a list of \$j \in \{1,\ldots,N\}\$ jobs with a processing time \$p_j\$ and a demand \$d_j\$ between 0 and 1. These are real numbers. Jobs require the fixed demand over the entirety of their processing time. We should not sort this list of jobs.

Our scheduling algorithm should do the following: Take the \$i^{th}\$ job from the list, and schedule it in the earliest time it is feasible. A job is feasibly scheduled at a time \$t\$ when the total demand of jobs that are being executed at time \$t\$ less than or equal to 1.

We construct a 2D array `X` of size N-by-3, where the columns are [start, completion, demand] and uses numpy.where to identify all jobs alive at time t. Using this construction, we scan over the time horizon. If a time t is feasible, we mark it as a candidate and keep scanning. If it has scanned a distance at least \$p_j\$ without breaking feasibility, then it means it can be scheduled at that candidate time point. Otherwise if it hit a snag before \$p_j\$, it means that none of the previous time points were feasible.

I am wondering if this can be sped up with smarter usage of numpy arrays or a different algorithm.

```py
import numpy as np
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from itertools import count
from numpy.testing import assert_almost_equal

@dataclass
class Job:
    p: float = 0
    d: float = 0
    S: float = None

    id: int = field(default_factory=count().__next__)  # Starts at 0


def schedule(jobs):
    # jobs is a list of job. A job object contains 4 attributes: An index id, p, d, and start time S (which is defaulted to None)

    # Three columns are start time, completion time, and  demand
    X = np.ones(shape=(len(jobs), 3)) * -1
    for job in jobs:
        makespan = np.max(X[:, 1], initial=0)
        t = 0
        S = None
        # Scan over the time horizon, while maintaining S that keeps track of earliest feasible start
        while t <= makespan + job.p:
            # Find all the jobs alive at time t. i.e. Start <= t < Completion
            alive_jobs = X[np.where((X[:, 0] <= t) & (t < X[:, 1]))]
            total_demand = np.sum(alive_jobs[:, 2])
            if total_demand + job.d <= 1:
                # t is a feasible start. Ensure the job fits for the entirety of its processing time
                if S is None:
                    S = t

                if S + job.p <= t:
                    # We have scanned over a horizon of at least p. This job is feasible
                    break
            else:
                # Could not feasibly schedule job over its processing time. Our candidate is not valid
                S = None

            # Advance time horizon by the earliest completion time of alive jobs.
            t = min(alive_jobs[:, 1]) if alive_jobs.size > 0 else t + job.p

        X[job.id, 0] = S
        X[job.id, 1] = S + job.p
        X[job.id, 2] = job.d

    return X


def main():
    # Random instance
    processing_times = [1, 6, 2, 4, 7, 3, 7, 8]
    demands = [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.2]

    desired_result = np.array([
        [0,   1,   0.2],  # First job is assigned at t=0, current resource usage is 0.2
        [0,   6,   0.3],  # Second job is assigned at t=0, since 0.2 + 0.3 = 0.5 <= 1
        [0,   2,   0.4],  # Third job can also start at t=0, with a current total resource use of 0.9 <= 1
        [2,   6,   0.5],  # Fourth job exceeds the current resource usage. It can't start when the first job finishes,
                          # because the total resource use at t=1 is 0.3 + 0.4 = 0.7. Therefore this job starts when
                          # the third job ends at t=2, with a total resource use 0.5 + 0.3 = 0.8
        [6,  13,   0.6],  # Fifth job has the same story as the fourth. The earliest feasible time it can start is t=6
        [13,  16,   0.7],
        [16,  23,   0.8],
        [1,   9,   0.2]  # The last job can actually start at t=1, because over the time t in [1,9) the resource use
                         # does not exceed 0.8. From [0, 2) the resource use is due to the second and third with total
                         # resource use 0.7. From [2, 6) the second and fourth jobs use 0.8 resources. From [6, 9),
                         # only the fifth job is alive, using only 0.8 resources.
    ])

    jobs = []
    for p, d in zip(processing_times, demands):
        jobs.append(Job(p=p, d=d))

    X = schedule(jobs)
    assert_almost_equal(X, desired_result)
    print(X)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is the business requirement of not being able to sort you jobs array? Does this mean your jobs have to run in the submitted order?

Comment: Yes the sorting of the jobs is controlled by another part of the program that will eventually call this function.

Comment: Show us how to run this, please. I'm looking for a [test suite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase), or at the very least `def main():` which supplies example data to exercise the code and describes what a correct result would look like. If this code is following something from the literature, please offer a citation.

Comment: @J_H I have provided a test case